# Angular2 map JSON to class with injectors

Tags: angular, typescript, serialization, angular2-services

I have the following class:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '../services/http.service'
export class Project {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ){
    }
    @JsonProperty('name')
    title: string;
    id:string;
    
    public getTitle(): string  {
        return this.title;
    }

    public getId(): string {
        return this.id;
    }

    public removeProject() {
        return this.http.delete("deleteurl"+this.id).map(() => {
            return true;
        })
    }

}
```

I want to deserialize json objects like this:

```js
import { JsonConvert } from "json2typescript";
getProjects():Observable<Project[]> {
        return this.http.get("getprojects").map((res:Response) => {
            var array: Project[] = [];
            for (let entry of res.json().files) {
                array.push(JsonConvert.deserializeObject(entry, Project));
            }
            return array;
        })
    }
```

If i want to map the json to my classes i get an error that they cannot create a class new project() because of the injected http service in the class project

How would you guys do this ? what is the best practise?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in HttpClient is getProjects method, you should import Injectable in the service file

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

this is for do dependency injection in you class Project in the constructor